# equivalence of $E[X_\infty]=1$ and $X$ is a u.i. martingale on $[0,\infty]$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $(X_t)$ be a strictly positive supermartingale on $[0,\infty)$. Hence $X_t$ covnerge to $X_\infty$ a.s. Now how can I show the following: $E[X_\infty]=1$ is equivalent to $(X_t)$ is a uniformly integrable martïngale on $[0,\infty]$.

hulik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result does not hold, as the following classical example shows. Let $U$ be uniform on $[0,1]$. For every $n\geqslant0$, let $U_n$ denote the integer part of $2^nU$, $\mathcal F_n=\sigma(U_n)$, and $X_n=2^n\cdot[U_n=0]$.

Then $(\mathcal F_n)$ is a filtration and $(X_n)$ is a nonnegative martingale with respect to $(\mathcal F_n)$, starting from $X_0=1$. Furthermore, $X_n\to X_{\infty}=0$ almost surely, hence $\mathrm E(X_{\infty})=0$, and $(X_n)$ is not uniformly integrable since $\mathrm E(X_n)=1$ does not converge to $\mathrm E(X_\infty)=0$.

For a strictly positive example, add a positive constant to each $X_n$.

---

**About the revised version:** Assume first that $(X_n)$ is in fact a martingale and that $\mathrm E(X_0)=1$.

In one direction, if $\mathrm E(X_\infty)=1$, then Scheffé's lemma ensures that $X_n\to X_\infty$ in $L^1$. Any sequence in $L^1$ which converges in $L^1$ is uniformly integrable hence $(X_n)$ is uniformly integrable. In the other direction, if $X_n\to X_\infty$ in $L^1$, $\mathrm E(X_n)\to \mathrm E(X_\infty)$. Since $\mathrm E(X_n)=1$ for every $n$, $\mathrm E(X_\infty)=1$. QED.

Finally, if one only assumes that $(X_n)$ is a supermartingale, what could impose that $(X_n)$ is in fact a martingale? To wit, consider the deterministic example $X_n=1+\frac1{n+1}$.

Comment: @ did: I'm so sorry! as you posted your answer I was starting to edit my question. It should be $E[X_\infty]=1$ Again, sorry!

Comment: @ did: Thank you for updating your answer. However, there still some questions around. First why is it true that, $E[X_n]\to E[X_\infty]$ (this is necessary to apply Scheffé's lemma.). Second, the generalization to a martingale: It would be clear if $E[X_0]=1$, otherwise I do not see how to adapt the case of supermartingale to martingal.

Comment: (1) The convergence of the expectations is a part of the *conclusion* of S lemma. (2) There is no *generalization to a martingale*. Rather the result holds for martingales and cannot hold for supermartingales.

Comment: @ did: Thanks again: to Scheffé: I know this result: $f,f_1,f_2,\dots \in L^1$ and $f_n \to f$ a.e. Then $E[|f_n|] \to E[|f|] \Rightarrow E[|f_n-f|]\to 0$. To obtain $L^1$ convergence I have to verify $E[|f_n|] \to E[|f|]$, right? Why is this true?

Comment: ?? $E(X_\infty)=E(X_n)=1$ for every $n$.

Comment: I agree if we assume $E[X_0]=1$. However, I do not see why I can assume this in my situation. Anyway, thanks for your help!